# How to avoid object is possibly null with useRef hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I use useRef hook

```
const secondaryCursor = React.useRef(null);
```

and use it into useEffect later:

```
positionRef.current.mouseY = mouseY - secondaryCursor.current.clientHeight / 2; //secondaryCursor.current -> TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'
```

Answer (score 1):

The "Object is possibly null" error is caused because the useRef() hook can be passed an initial value as an argument and we're passing it null as an initial value.

Updated your code as follows if you are sure it won't be null.

```
positionRef.current.mouseY = mouseY - secondaryCursor.current!.clientHeight / 2;
```

This link contains many other ways to do so.

Refer:
[https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-useref-object-is-possibly-null#:~:text=The%20%22Object%20is%20possibly%20null%22%20error%20is%20caused%20because%20the,initialized%20to%20the%20passed%20argument](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-useref-object-is-possibly-null#:%7E:text=The%20%22Object%20is%20possibly%20null%22%20error%20is%20caused%20because%20the,initialized%20to%20the%20passed%20argument).

Comment: What about `positionRef.current`?

Comment: It's worth warning that you should only use `x!.y` if you know for certain it won't be `null` (in this case, just adding that with the context we have might cause an error at run time if it actually is `null`)

Comment: I can do the same with that as well. But as above he defined secondaryCursor so updated that accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The ref's `current` property will be `null` until/unless it's set. In your case, you're using it in a `useEffect` callback, so assuming you've used the ref on an element that was rendered, it won't be `null` when you try to use it. But TypeScript doesn't know that, so it warns you of this possible error.

There are (at least) three ways to deal with it, each with pros and cons:

1. Don't try to use it if it's `null` (for instance, using an `if`).

   ```typescript
   if (positionRef.current && secondaryCursor.current) {
       positionRef.current.mouseY = mouseY - secondaryCursor.current.clientHeight / 2;
   }
   ```

   If it's `null` when the code runs, the code won't do anything. If you were sure it wouldn't be `null` when this code ran, silently not doing anything may be hard to debug. But if you're not sure whether it will be set, you'd use a guard like that to avoid using it if it isn't.
2. If you're **sure** it can't be `null`, use an assertion function to assert that (with a runtime check so that you get an informative error if the assertion is incorrect):

   ```typescript
   assertNotNullish(positionRef.current);
   assertNotNullish(secondaryCursor.current);
   positionRef.current.mouseY = mouseY - secondaryCursor.current.clientHeight / 2;
   ```

   ...where `assertNotNullish` is a utility function like this:

   ```typescript
   function assertNotNullish<T>(value: T | null | undefined): asserts value is T {
       if (value == null) {
           throw new Error(`Expected non-nullish value, got ${String(value)}`);
       }
   }
   ```

   The only downside here is that if you're sure it won't be `null`, you're running a *very very very quick* test unnecessarily.
3. If you're **sure** it can't be `null`, use the not-nullish assertion type operator (a postfix `!`).

   ```typescript
   positionRef.current!.mouseY = mouseY - secondaryCursor.current!.clientHeight / 2;
   // −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^
   ```

   There's no runtime aspect to that at all, you're just telling TypeScript you know it won't be `null`. If the assertion is wrong, you'll still get an error at runtime, but it won't be as clear as it would be with #2.